# how to increase RAM allocation for Maya in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, performance, memory, maya

Having a bitmap displayed as a blueprint and doing poly modeling gets slow in Maya 2010. 
Any options to feed it more RAM? Any performance tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick search and it would appear that you [can't assign more RAM to an app](http://macosx.com/tech-support/Mac/assign-more-memory-app-in-OS-x/331392.HTML) in OSX. The link explains how OSX uses RAM.

Any chance you can hide some of the poly mesh to see if that helps. I'd presume with a large image that would also slow things down.